# How to parse a json having nested json type objects with boost

Tags: c++, json, boost

I have a json which looks like

```
{
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "path": "hutchison",
      "state": 16,
      "url": "https://go.gl/",
      "id": "ZXNrb0luZGlh",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "type",
          "name": "type",
          "propertyType": "string",
          "value": "COMPANY"
        },
        {
          "id": "folderify",
          "name": "folderify",
          "propertyType": "boolean",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "id": "name",
          "name": "name",
          "propertyType": "string",
          "value": "yum"
        }
      ],
      "content": [],
      "createdBy": "00ui3tqahuu6bwMhU0i6",
      "creationDate": 1497348318103,
      "modificationDate": 1499082955407,
      "modifiedBy": "00ui3tqahuu6bwMhU0i6"
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "path": "test",
      "state": 13,
      "url": "https://ODE/v0/test",
      "id": "YW5ib3Rlc3Q=",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "name": "string",
          "propertyType": "string",
          "value": "string"
        }
      ],
      "content": [],
      "createdBy": "00u33355JQXgmzqO90i5",
      "creationDate": 1498463285568,
      "modificationDate": 1498463356176,
      "modifiedBy": "00u33355JQXgmzqO90i5"
    },
    {
      "name": "KE",
      "path": "KE",
      "state": 4,
      "url": "https://full.com/NODE/v0/DEKE",
      "id": "REVLRQ==",
      "properties": [
        {
          "id": "type",
          "name": "type",
          "propertyType": "string",
          "value": "COMPANY"
        },
        {
          "id": "folderify",
          "name": "folderify",
          "propertyType": "boolean",
          "value": "true"
        },
        {
          "id": "name",
          "name": "name",
          "propertyType": "string",
          "value": "KE"
        }
      ],
      "content": [],
      "createdBy": "00uy9bswhaVnUggF00i6",
      "creationDate": 1498805345347,
      "modificationDate": 1498805346371,
      "modifiedBy": "00uy9bswhaVnUggF00i6"
    }
]
,
  "name": "",
  "path": "",
  "state": 27,
  "url": "https://go.gl/ODE/v0",
  "id": "ROOT",
  "properties": [],
  "content": [],
  "createdBy": "INITIAL",
  "creationDate": 1497261853581,
  "modificationDate": 1498805345347,
  "modifiedBy": "00uy9bswhaVnUggF00i6"
}
```

I want each and every key-value(s) pair to be traversed once by of course using boost library (any other approach in cpp is also welcomed), to later save them in relevant containers.

Comment: And? have you tried anything? please post your code and where you are stuck. we cannot just write code for you!

Comment: I want a two piece and a biscuit but there isn't a KFC close to me.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet traverses each and every key pair and stores it in the relevant collections:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;

int main() {
    ptree pt;
    std::ifstream ifs("input.txt");
    read_json(ifs, pt);
}
```

The collections form a tree. Notably, a Property Tree. This may or may not be what you need, because your objectives weren't given.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually using [Json for modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) to manage any Json. It's really intuitive and easy to integrate.

I don't really know which key-value you're trying to reach but let's say you'd like to store the name of the first children in a string variable.

You'd parse your json like so:

```
json yourJson = json::parse(yourJsonString);
```

Then you'd access the name and store it in a string variable like so:

```
string nameFirstChildren = yourJson["children"][0]["name"].get<string>();
```

Then, you can save it in a container of your choice or you could just do it without using a string variable before saving it to your container.

Whatever works for you!

You could also use [RapidJson](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson)